# VoIP and Vlan implementation

Tags: vlan, voip

I'm implmenting VoIP on our network across 30 buildings on a University campus. Would it be best to put all the VoIP phones into a single vlan or splits them in separate vlans for each building?  Am using a software based PBX system (Asterisk).

Comment: How many phones? How good network?

Comment: Could potential expand to about 450 phones on a fibre network with a 10Gbps back bone. Running Cisco 6500 core and distribution L3 switches.

Comment: Should not make a difference then. One VLAN should be enough. 450 phoens is not a lot of load SIP wise, and for the RTP traffic it should not be a lot and makes no difference either.

Comment: @TomTom Thanks for your advice. At what quantity of VoIP phone would you suggest separate vlans. And what would be your implementation method? Just for knowledge and reference

Comment: Depends, but possibly 4 digits. Phones are very static, little updates, low traffic. 450 phones possibly does no mean a lot of stuff around. I would definitely route the normal lan, but a sip phone vlan... sounds like very inactive to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is really more of a 'it depends' thing.  Keep in mind that any more configuration you do will add to your management overhead.  One advantage of putting them all in a separate subnet/VLAN is that you might be able to do better QoS or anything on them.